# Bash - Move a number into a specific string location

Tags: bash, numbers, location, output, move

I'm trying to understand how I can change the script so that the output files aren't `TEST.doc` , `TEST.doc1`, `TEST.doc12`, ect., but instead `TEST.doc`, `TEST_1.doc`, `TEST_2.doc`, etc. More simply, right before specific known `.extension` .(`txt|rtf|pages|numbers|keynote|doc|docx|xls|ppt|pdf`).

How can I do this?

Here the script

```
#!/bin/bash

rename_files() {
   title="${1##*${2} - }"
   for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
   case "${filename##*.}" in
     txt|rtf|pages|numbers|keynote|doc|docx|xls|ppt|pdf)
       mkdir -p -m 777 "/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/${title}"
       new_path="/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
       let "iters=1"
       while [ -f "$new_path" ] ; do
          new_path=$new_path"$iters"
          let "iters++"
       done
       echo "moving $filename -> $new_path"
       mv "${filename}" "${new_path}"
       ;;
   esac
   done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloads/${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category DOC
```

**EDIT**:

```
fromdir="/Users/Desktop/Downloads/"  
todir="/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/${2}/"

rename_files() {
   title="${1##*${2} - }"
   let "iters=0"
   for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
     case "${filename##*.}" in txt|rtf|pages|numbers|keynote|doc|docx|xls|ppt|pdf)
         new_path="${todir}/${2}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
            new_path=$new_path  # removed "$iters"
            let "iters++"
            # extract $path without dot + extension
            new_path_basename=${new_path%*.*};
            # Extract extension from $path
            ext=${new_path##*.};
            echo "moving $filename -> ${new_path_basename}_${iters}.${ext}"
            # Add ${iters} before extension
            mv "${filename}" "${new_path_basename}_${iters}.${ext}"
         ;;
     esac
   done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "${fromdir}${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category DOC
rename_category PRJ
```

Before:

```
/Users/Desktop/Downloads/DOC - TESTDOC/AFile.doc
                                      /AnotherFile.doc

/Users/Desktop/Downloads/PRJ - TESTPRJ/AFile.pdf
                                      /AnotherFile.pdf
```

After:

```
/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/DOC/TESTDOC_1.doc
                                             /TESTDOC_2.doc

/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/PRJ/TESTPRJ_1.pdf
                                             /TESTPRJ_2.pdf
```

**EDIT2**:

There are two test files:
`big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4` and `big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb copy.mp4`

The output log

```
sh Script.sh

moving /Users/Desktop/Downloads/MOV - TEST/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb copy.mp4 -> /Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/MOV/TEST_1.mp4

cp /Users/Desktop/Downloads/MOV - TEST/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb copy.mp4 /Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/MOV/TEST_1.mp4

moving /Users/Desktop/Downloads/MOV - TEST/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4 -> /Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/MOV/TEST_2.mp4

cp /Users/Desktop/Downloads/MOV - TEST/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4 /Users/albertorapolla/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/MOV/TEST_2.mp4
```

**EDIT3**:

Last update of the script (not the "special" one)

```
#!/bin/bash

fromdir="/Users/Desktop/Downloads/"
todir="/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/"

rename_files() {
    title="${1##*${2} - }"
    exttitle="${2}"
    iters=0
    numfiles=$(ls -l "$1/"*.* | wc -l)
    for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
      new_path="${todir}${title}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
      iters=_$(( ++i ))
      # extract $path without dot + extension
      new_path_basename=${new_path%*.*};
      # Extract extension from $path
      ext=${new_path##*.};
      if [ "$numfiles" -eq 1 ]; then
          iters=""
      fi
      case "${filename##*.}" in txt|rtf|pages|numbers|keynote|doc|docx|xls|ppt|pdf)
        mkdir -p -m 777 "${todir}${title}"
        echo "moving $filename -> ${new_path_basename}${iters}.${ext}"
        # Add ${iters} before extension
        mv "${filename}" "${new_path_basename}${iters}.${ext}"
      ;;
      esac
    done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "${fromdir}${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category DOC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (comments are in the script) :

```
rename_files() {
    title="${1##*${2} - }"
    exttitle="${2}"
    iters=0
    numfiles=$(ls -l "$1/"*.* | wc -l)
    for filename in "$1/"*.*; do
      new_path="${todir}${exttitle}/${title}.${filename##*.}"
      iters=_$(( ++i ))
      # extract $path without dot + extension
      new_path_basename=${new_path%*.*};
      # Extract extension from $path
      ext=${new_path##*.};
      if [ "$numfiles" -eq 1 ]; then
          iters=""
      fi
      case "${filename##*.}" in txt|rtf|pages|numbers|keynote|doc|docx|xls|ppt|pdf)
        mkdir -p -m 777 "${todir}${exttitle}"
        echo "moving $filename -> ${new_path_basename}${iters}.${ext}"
        # Add ${iters} before extension
        mv "${filename}" "${new_path_basename}${iters}.${ext}"
      ;;
      esac
    done
}

rename_category() {
  for path in "${fromdir}${1}"*; do
    rename_files "$path" "$1"
  done
}

rename_category DOC
```

Comment: It seems to overwrite the same file. As output file now I have only `/Documents Share/Downloaded/TEST/TEST_1.doc`, but output log is `moving /Users/Desktop/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-100kb.doc -> /Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc`
`moving /Users/Desktop/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-200kb.doc -> /Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc`
`moving /Users/Desktop/Downloads/DOC - TEST/Sample-doc-file-500kb.doc -> /Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/TEST/TEST.doc`.

Comment: It doesn't run properly. It only creates `TEST` folder.

Comment: Updated. I removed the `while` block, it's useless (you check a non existing file). And added 2 global variables for source and destination dirs.

Comment: Tried now but it doesn't work: it doesn't create `/Downloaded/TEST` folder; no output log. P.S. : I tested with folders as your updated script, but actually `Downloaded` and `Downloads` aren't in the same folder: it is `Desktop/Downloads` and `Desktop/Documents Shares/Downloaded`

Comment: Found the issue: probably I was not clear enough about folder paths and I noticed now that in your script fromdir and todir are reversed (Downloads is where the files are and not in Downloaded, where the files go). So, thank you very much, you solved my issue!

Comment: One last thing: so `while` block it's completely useless now?

Comment: More than useless : it checks a file that does not exist yet. None of the instructions in this block would be executed.

Comment: Sorry, I have some doubts: the first is that I noticed that even if there's only one file it appends `_1`; is it possible to add it only if there's more that one file? The last doubt is about a specific use of the script: see **EDIT** where I explain the situation. In that case, is it correct to only add `${2}` to `todir` and `new_path`, removing `mkdir` or I have to modify something else? Because of it seems to work but I don't know if it's just luck.

Comment: `$2`is not available when `todir` is defined. I updated.

Comment: Tried now but it doesn't work properly: first I tried as you updated, but it doesn't run at all; so I added `rename_category MOV` and the result is only a `TEST` folder in `/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/`; no file.  See **EDIT2** for the log. P.S.: not sure that `${exttitle}` is linked to the extension of the file, but I precise that the name before  `-` (for example `MOV - TEST`) isn't linked to the file extension (for example the file can be `File.avi` but I call the folder `MOV - TEST` because of it's a movie file).

Comment: Sorry, `mv` was replaced with an `echo` for testing, it could not work. It should be ok now.

Comment: All works fine now: one file and more than one file. There's only one strange error: it creates an empty `TEST` folder in `/Users/Desktop/Documents Share/Downloaded/`, next to `MOV` folder. It does not result from the logs.

Comment: Updated. Tell me if it's ok.

Comment: Woks perfectly! Only one question: with this last script you solved the only one file issue (`_1` with only one file) but this script version is for a specific situation, and I need the old one too. How can implement this correction to the old one version (should be edit3 of your script)?

Comment: Just remove (or comment) the `if` block : `if [ "$numfiles" -eq 1 ]; then iters="" fi`.

Comment: No, that correction is mandatory. I mean, now it moves files to a folder named `DOC`, so that all files goes there, and that's OK, because for that files I don't need a specific folder. But the initial script (your EDIT3 - 4hrs ago) creates a unique folder such as `TEST` if the initial folder was `DOC - TEST` but it had the _1 error. What lines I have to add to that script to solve this issue?

Comment: Found the solution: I simply changed `${ext title}` with `${title}`. See **EDIT3** and tell me if there's something wrong.

Comment: Right. The value of `${title}` is the string after ` - `.